# image not uploaded in image directory but store name in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

Controller code:

```
public function create(){

    $row = $this->model->set_attribute( ( isset( $_POST["model"] ) )?$_POST["model"]:array() );

    if( !empty( $_POST["model"] ) ){


        $rand = rand( 10000000, 9999999 ). '_';
        if( !empty( $_FILES['model']['name']['image'] ) ){
            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['model']['tmp_name']['image'], FCPATH. '/assets/uploads/'. $rand. $_FILES['model']['name']['image'] );
            $_POST['model']['image'] = $rand. $_FILES['model']['name']['image'];
        }
        $id = $this->model->insert( $_POST["model"] );
        if( $id != null ){
            $row = $this->model->get( $id );
            app::set_flash( "success", "Record is added." );
            $this->_redirect( "index" );
        }
    }
    $this->_render( "form", array(
        "model" => $this->model,
        "page_heading" => $this->page_heading,
        "row" => $row,
    ) );
}
views
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="image"><?php echo( $model->attributeLabels( 'image' ) ); ?> <small class="danger highlight "><?php echo form_error( 'image' ) ?></small></label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="model[image]" id="main_image" placeholder="<?php echo( $model->attributeLabels( 'image' ) ); ?>" value="<?php echo $row->image; ?>" />
            <?php echo( $row->image ); ?>
        </div>
```

In the above controller function   are store the image name in database but not upload the image in image directory assets/uploads

Comment: Did you try codeigniter upload library?

Comment: post the form html code...!

Comment: no  i am using upload the image using this line of code

Comment: can you have echo this path "$_FILES['model']['tmp_name']['image'], FCPATH. '/assets/uploads/'. $rand. $_FILES['model']['name']['image']"..see it is proper or not..and then give permission to the uploads folder to 777

Comment: Can you please add the code of view file as well?

Comment: i have added the views code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should have attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" are missed in form